# deleting node from a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a function to delete a node from a binary search tree.  I got the third case with node having 2 children working, but my code doesn't work it the node has 1 or no children.

Here is the code I copied directly from the book. Is this code I got from the book wrong?

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::deleteFromTree
(nodeType<elemType>* &p)
{
nodeType<elemType> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
nodeType<elemType> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
nodeType<elemType> *temp; //pointer to delete the node
if (p == NULL)
cout << "Error: The node to be deleted is NULL."
<< endl;
else if (p->lLink == NULL && p->rLink == NULL)
{
temp = p;
p = NULL;
delete temp;
}
else if (p->lLink == NULL)
{
temp = p;
p = temp->rLink;
delete temp;
}
else if (p->rLink == NULL)
{
temp = p;
p = temp->lLink;
delete temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your code is working perfectly with 2 children? Because the above snippet you provided only takes care of 3 cases: (1) no children, (2) 1 children pointed by left ptr, (3) 1 children pointed by right ptr... The last case, where there are 2 children, is simply not present...

So to answer your question: yes, the above code, as you provided, seems to be wrong (a.k.a. incomplete).

I managed to track down the source of what you are using. Do you have the following code inside the function shown above (appended after your stream of `else if`), or is it absent?

```
else
{
    current = p->llink;
    trailCurrent = NULL;

    while(current->rlink != NULL)
    {
        trailCurrent = current;
        current = current->rlink;
    } //end while

    p->info = current->info;

    if(trailCurrent == NULL) //current did not move; 
                             //current == p->llink; adjust p
        p->llink = current->llink;
    else
        trailCurrent->rlink = current->llink;

    delete current;
}//end else
```

Comment: yeah i have that part in it... i just left it out because it was working.